# embed youtube video playlist in ebay cant use iframe or <object?

Tags: iframe, youtube, embed

I am trying to embed youtube playlist videos in ebay.. so far nothing has worked.. cant use a iframe or

```
 <iframe width="420" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/j-IV87qQ00M"      frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: I just talked to two people at ebay and they both told me they are disabling playlists all together..... ?

Answer (score 0):

One method to embed YouTube in your ebay auction is to share the YouTube video with the "use old YouTube embed code" checkbox checked and then you can copy the embed code for it. Of course it's not html5 but until ebay allows the iframe tag, at least it works for everyone except ios.